# LINUX Permission issues

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Can anyone help me in fixing the permission issues in Linux.

I am new to Linux and i am trying to run a script called buildAll.sh

by moving to that specific directory and i typed `./buildAll.sh` the response i got was

```
./buildAll.sh: 16: ./buildAll.sh: ./buildJS.sh: Permission denied
```

i tried to run using `sudo ./buildAll.sh` , but that didn't work.

Then i tried with `chmod -r 777 buildAll.sh` and again i tried to run that script but no change.

I have a folder called build which has some dependency can be seen a folder with locked picture.

Can anyone help me to run the script without having the permission issues please

Comment: Every time you do `chmod 777`, somewhere in the world a kitten dies.

Comment: Can you please give us `ls -la buildAll.sh buildJS.sh`?

You may have a problem with both _ownership_ AND _permissions_.

Comment: `chmod -r 777./buildAll.sh` also removed read access to buildAll.sh, it's a capital -R for recursive. But don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

in line 16 your script seems to call buildJS.sh and the permissions OF THAT seem to be incorrect

Comment: Same as the other answer: sudo chmod +x buildJS.sh

Answer (score 2):

You obviously have a pervasive permissions problem. Why don't you just start again, unpack the files into a new directory **without** using `sudo` or `su`, and then use `chmod +x` on the files that need to be executable?

Answer (score 1):

sudo chmod +x buildAll.sh

Should do the trick

Comment: hi i tried that asked for sudo password, after that again i gave the command sudo ./builAll.sh   . The response was rm: cannot remove ‘build’: Permission denied
cp: cannot stat ‘./build/.svn’: Permission denied
cp: cannot stat ‘./build/compiler.jar’: Permission denied
cp: cannot stat ‘./build/buildJS.sh’: Permission denied
touch: setting times of ‘build’: Permission denied
./buildAll.sh: line 14: cd: build: Permission denied
./buildAll.sh: line 16: ./buildJS.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: @user1009686 So your script is trying to fiddle with a whole bunch of files that is owned by another user - which you do not have permission to do. The error also mentions a `./buildJS.sh`, so you might need to make that file executable too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems by the error message the issue is with `buildJS.sh`.  If `buildJS.sh` is not in your current directory (it might not be as `buildAll.sh` might be changing directories), find `buildJS.sh` and then:

```
chmod +x ${directory_where_found}/buildJS.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Since .sh files should have executable permissions by default you can do this:

```
cd $YOUR_DIRECTORY
find . -name '*.sh' -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried with `sudo chmod +x buildAll.sh`
>
> ```
> rm: cannot remove ‘build’: Permission denied
> cp: cannot stat ‘./build/.svn’: Permission denied
> cp: cannot stat ‘./build/compiler.jar’: Permission denied
> cp: cannot stat ‘./build/buildJS.sh’: Permission denied
> touch: setting times of ‘build’: Permission denied
> ./buildAll.sh: line 14: cd: build: Permission denied
> ./buildAll.sh: line 16: ./buildJS.sh: No such file or directory
> ```

You have given permission only to run your script. However, this doesn't mean that you have permission for all of instructions launched by the script. The error message is there to prove it ;) .

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with a file, which I solved by just right-clicking the file and selecting properties. Thereafter I just went to the permissions tab and gave it read/write access.

Not a very pretty or linux way of doing things, but it worked for me.